# Cómo destroy una sesion de PHP en Javscript? (NO AJAX)

Tags: php, javascript

Necesito crear una función en JS que me destruya la sesión actual en PHP, en PHP haría un `session_destroy()` pero en JS no me deja.

Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que deberías usar `AJAX` para destruir.

**.js código:**

```
function destroy_session(){
    var xmlhttp = getXmlHttp();
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open('GET','./destroy_session.php', true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
       if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
          if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
             alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
         }
       }
    };
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

**destroy_session.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION = array();
    if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
       $params = session_get_cookie_params();
       setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
       );
    }
    session_destroy();
    echo 'Session was destroyed';
?>
```

Fuente: Traducción de [Destroy PHP SESSION in Javascript Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23126582/destroy-php-session-in-javascript-function)

Comment: Sabes cómo podría hacerlo sin usar AJAX?

Comment: No vas a poder ya que PHP es ServerSide, por lo que sus sesiones también son de servidor. Javascript es el lado del cliente. Tienes que acceder de algún modo al servidor para poder destruirla.